# Is environmental routing possible?

Tags: routes, multi-environment

In the general.php config file, I can target settings for multi-environments like so:

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    'devMode' => false
  ),

  '.loc' => array(
    'devMode' => true
  )
);
```

**Is it possible to do something similar in the routes.php file too?**

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    'test' => 'index'
  ),

  '.loc' => array(
    'test' => '_test/index'
  )
);
```

I don't want to differentiate the locales, but the environment instead. I know it's possible to query how content gets included within the templates themselves. I just wondered if this is possible instead... I don't actually have a use-case example.

Maybe a time will arise where I want to allow certain content to be accessible for 'staging.' domains only.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `routes.php` config file doesn't support multi-environment setups in the manner that `general.php` or `db.php` does – in other words, your example code using a multidimensional array would throw an error.

As a workaround, you can write some PHP in your `routes.php` file. For simple stuff, a ternary operator may suffice:

```
return array(
    'test' => strpos(CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT, '.loc') !== false ? '_test/index' : 'index', 
);
```

For more complex stuff, you could set up different arrays of routes for different enviroments, and maybe do some merging:

```
$routes = array(
    'foo' => '_foo',
    'bar' => '_bar',
);

$devRoutes = array(
    'baz' => '_baz',
);

$stagingRoutes = array(
    'baz' => '_staging/baz',
);

if (strpos(CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT, '.loc') !== false) {
    $routes = array_merge($routes, $devRoutes);
} else if (strpos(CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT, '.staging') !== false) {
    $routes = array_merge($routes, $stagingRoutes);
}

return $routes;
```

If you're wondering about the [`CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT`](https://craftcms.com/docs/php-constants#craft-environment) constant, that'll default to your hostname (e.g. `myawesomesite.loc`) unless you explicitly set it to something else before bootstrapping Craft (e.g. in your `index.php` file). The simple `strpos(CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT, $env)` test is how Craft merges multi-enviroment configs (e.g. from `general.php`) [under the hood](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/ConfigService.php#L861).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; this works. I never even knew you could query the CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT like that. In practice I can see if this were used as a way to redirect users somewhere generic (like in my example), there would be no way to define a Canonical link within the template. So very bad for SEO. In very rare cases this might be handy; for now I'm just happy it is possible and clean to do. Thanks again.

Comment: Is `CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT` still the recommended way to get at this value in Craft 3? I see it does work and `craft.app.environment` doesn't…